# What prevents bootstrap/foundation from working with Google Sites?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

Google sites supports css,  but bootstrap/foundation will not work. Why?

What is the technical limitation? Have they blocked it specifically or is all CSS not the same?

Comment: I'm willing to bet there's a flaw in your code. Post your code or make a JSfiddle so the community can help.

Comment: Voted to close because there was no example mentioned. No code was added.

Comment: Have any of you people down voting or commenting ever used Google sites?  Perhaps you should stick to topics you know something about rather than making assumptions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using responsive design within Google Sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537744/using-responsive-design-within-google-sites)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is pretty much covered here : [Using responsive design within Google Sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537744/using-responsive-design-within-google-sites) ,

I've never used GoogleSites but looking on their website and some other questions on here pretty much make clear there is no way of supplying your own CSS or even setting the ViewPort so... No, you can't use Foundation or any other framework, you can barely even use your own CSS. Maybe invest in a cheap proper host if your serious about web work.